# Highest power of 2 factor of $N!$ is equal to $2 ^{N - {\rm sum\ of\ bits}}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial, binary

I am reading on this [page](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/binarysplitfact.html) a formula stating that the **largest power of 2** contained (as a factor) in $n!$ has the following exponent:

$n -$ number of bits that are equal to $1$, in the binary representation of $n$

Can you explain, in the simplest possible way, why this is true. (I am aware of the [Legendre](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identit%C3%A0_di_Legendre-de_Polignac) formula, but right now I do not seem able to connect the dots.)

Comment: @DonThousand: That's $n$ *minus* number of bits, not $n$ *equals* number of bits (after all, $n$ is already given as the number of which the factorial is taken). In the case of $4!$, the formula gives $4-1=3$.

Comment: @DonThousand: n would be 4 in your case. Number of bits in 4 is 1 ( 4 = 0100 base 2). So the 2 factor would have exponent 4 -1 = 3. Btw, I am not doubting the statement, as the program works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does come out of Legendre's formula.  First note that, for $n$ a power of $2$
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac n{2^i}\right\rfloor=\frac n2+\frac n4+\ldots +1=n-1$$
and $n$ in binary has one $1$ bit, so the formula is satisfied.
Now note that if $n,m$ are both powers of $2$ with $n \gt m$, $n+m$ has two bits and
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac {n+m}{2^i}\right\rfloor=\frac n2+\frac n4+\ldots +1+\frac m2+\frac m4+\ldots +1=n-1+m-1=n+m-2$$
because all the divisions come out even until the one where $2^i=m$, then the $n$ divisions are coming out even so we can ignore $m$ in the later ones.  This extends to any number of summands.

Comment: Thank you, very nice argument! btw, why did you use n>m, does not seem even necessary ?

Comment: Just to be specific in the argument that the divisions of $m$ by $2^i$ will fall below $1$ before the divisions of $2^n$

Comment: @ Ross Millikan, ah great!